# NestJS + Pino Logger appears only partially

Tags: typescript, logging, nestjs, pino

I have implemented the Pino Logger (`iamolegga/nestjs-pino`) like described in the documentation, into my NestJS application. And I can see the startup messages like route mappings and controller initialization, as well as "incoming request" and "request completed". See code below.

But as soon as I use the logger inside a service or controller of mine (see document.service.ts), the logs do not appear in the console.

```js
// main.ts
import { bootstrap } from "./app";

// Start development server
bootstrap()
    .then(async (app) => {
        await app.listen(process.env.LISTEN_PORT, "0.0.0.0");
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

```js
// app.ts
export async function bootstrap() {
    let fastifyAdapter = new FastifyAdapter({
        logger: pinoOptions,
        trustProxy: true,
    } as FastifyServerOptions);

    const app = await NestFactory.create<NestFastifyApplication>(AppModule, fastifyAdapter, { bufferLogs: true });

    // pino logger
    app.useLogger(app.get(Logger));
    app.useGlobalInterceptors(new LoggerErrorInterceptor());

    await app.init();
    return app;
}
```

```js
// app.module.ts
import { Module } from "@nestjs/common";
import { TypeOrmModule, TypeOrmModuleOptions } from "@nestjs/typeorm";
import { Params } from "nestjs-pino/params";

@Module({
    imports: [
        LoggerModule.forRoot({
            pinoHttp: pinoOptions,
        } as Params),
        TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
            useFactory: async (logger: PinoLogger): Promise<TypeOrmModuleOptions> => {
                return {
                    ...(await getDataSourceConfig()),
                    autoLoadEntities: true,
                    logger: new PinoTypeormLogger(logger),
                };
            },
            inject: [PinoLogger],
        }),
        AnnouncementModule,
        // more modules excluded
    ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

```js
// app-logger.ts
import { PinoLoggerOptions } from "fastify/types/logger";

export const pinoOptions: PinoLoggerOptions = {
    level: "debug",
    transport: {
        targets: [
            {
                target: "pino-pretty",
                level: "debug",
                options: {
                    name: "terminal",
                    colorize: false,
                    singleLine: true,
                },
            },
        ],
    },
    redact: { paths: ["req.headers.authorization", "req.headers.cookie"], censor: "**REDACTED**" },
};
```

```js
// document.service.ts
@Injectable()
export class DocumentService {
    private readonly logger = new Logger(DocumentService.name);
        async getDocument() {
                this.logger.info("This does not appear in the console!");
        }
        
}
```

Does anybody have an idea what the cause of this could be?

Answer (score 0):

realneo, you try to change the logger level at your config? Because your transport only specific debug, and you try to log info level.

```
transport: {
        targets: [
            {
                target: "pino-pretty",
                level: "info",
                options: {
                    name: "terminal",
                    colorize: false,
                    singleLine: true,
                },
            },
```